# How to mount folder inside an OSS bucket to ECS instance?

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I am able to mount the OSS bucket with the ECS instance normally,

```
./ossutil mb oss://<bucketname> --acl=public-read --endpoint=oss-ap-south-1.aliyuncs.com

ossfs <bucket-name> <local-folder-path> -ourl=http://oss-ap-south-1.aliyuncs.com
```

but now I want to mount the folder inside the OSS bucket to the ECS instance, the goal is to use the same OSS bucket for multiple instances by differentiating with folders inside the bucket

how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: What does the **but now I want to mount the folder inside the OSS bucket instance, how can I do that?** mean? Please clarify.

Comment: @wojcieh updated the question

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, in this scenario, you might try to work with permissions assigned to a mounted bucket into a directory. However, this scenario might simply not work.

https://github.com/aliyun/ossfs/wiki/FAQ-EN#11

https://github.com/aliyun/ossfs/wiki/FAQ-EN#12

The other idea could be a dedicated RAM policy created for each directory. For example:

**Directory1**
directory1 -> RAM policy 1
(directory1) -> read-only access to all other directories and full read-write to a single directory.

**Directory2**
directory2 -> RAM policy 2
(directory2) -> read-only access to all other directories and full read-write to a single directory.

And so on.